# MarkLogic 8 and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic and one of the thing that attracted me to MarkLogic was support for RDF and SPARQL...
Does MarkLogic allow SPARQL on non-RDF data? In other words, is it possible to query data from XML and RDF at the same time?

Comment: If the provided answer fulfils your needs, please mark it as so. Otherwise, if you expand on you question, we can expand on the answer until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  You can embed triples in both JSON and XML documents.  This allows you to do things like do an and-query with some sparql based search constraints and mix it with other query constraints on XML elements.

This makes more sense if you understand fragments in MarkLogic and that each search query returns the fragments that match that query.

If you expand on your question, we can expand more on the answer.